# Connect to a VPN Connection in Ubuntu in bash

Tags: linux, bash, vpn

How can I connect to a `VPN Connection` when I can use only bash (terminal)?

I create a connection but I want to connect or disconnect using remote ssh connection

Comment: This belongs on serverfault.  Also, please add information as to the kind of VPN connection to which you would like to connect, and more information about the steps taken so far.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to see the community expectation for quality questions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use `nmcli` to do that. this program is use for network management.

```
nmcli con up id <name_of_connection>
```

you need to save the password of that connection before you use this command. For more information, try `man nmcli`

any help on how to create VPN_CONNECTION in bash and how to manage them will appreciate

Comment: `nmcli` won't let me do anything. Just getting `Error: Could not create NMClient object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.` no matter what I do

Answer (score 3):

Install the packages

```
  sudo apt-get install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

and then from bash you can try

vpnc-connect *vpn.conf*

you need to supply the vpn configuration file as argument.